# c++11 - list-initialization of an aggregate from an aggrrgate

Tags: c++, initialization, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization

On [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) of the cppreference.com I read the following:

> If T is an aggregate class and the braced-init-list has a single
> element of the same or derived type (possibly cv-qualified), the
> object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
> copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
> direct-list-initialization).

But [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) states this:

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - array type
> - class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>   no private data members
>   no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors

But if an aggregate class has no user defined constructors, how it could be initialized in a manner stipulated above? I mean, it is not saying that aggregate members are getting their values from the members of the initializer, it explicitly mentions the constructor from the initializer.

---

PS1
It seems like this one is a good exemplification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class A {
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        //this one does nothing to the code below:
        //A()         = delete; 
        //this one does BOOM
        //A(A &other) = delete;  
    private:
};

int 
main()
{
    if( !std::is_aggregate<A>::value ) {
        std::cout << "A is not aggregate!" << std::endl;
    }
    A a = { 1, 2 };
    A b = { a };

    std::cout << "a is " << a.a << " " << a.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b is " << b.a << " " << b.b << std::endl;
}
```

So, copy constructor it is, I guess.

---

PS2

I have the same behavior when compiling without `std::is_aggregate` and with c++11 flag on.

Comment: [mre] please, so that we can see what you're driving at.  Which, when you put one together, will show you that it does actually work :)

Comment: @PaulSanders ahhh, so it is calling the implicitly-defined copy constructor and is direct-initializes the members?

Comment: No, it will call the implicitly-defined normal constructor.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow hey, thank for the reply! I can clearly see it working in code, but I cannot see why. cppreference page for default constructors says that implicitly-defined-constructor has the `same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list.` How come members are not default inited a.k.a. filled with garbage in this case?

Comment: What the paragraph is saying I think is that `Foo bar; ... Foo foo{bar};` is the same as `Foo foo = bar;` and not like `Foo foo{1,2,3,4, ...};` where each argument is assigned to one member of the `foo` and any missing are zero/default initialized.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yes, but...doesn't `Foo foo = bar` involve copy constructor?

Comment: copy initialization is what the text says.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yeah, but you wrote about the normal one. Anyways, I think I can exemplify what I'm talking about, gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> of the same or derived type

That means that default copy-constructor will be used. That's why there is no contradiction between these two rules